# highcharts with scrollbar, how to display all items on download image?

Tags: highcharts

The download image cannot display all items, 
as you can see it will follow scrollbar.

## Current download image

#### image 1 highcharts with scrollbar download image cannot show all items

[image: highcharts with scrollbar download image cannot show all items]

#### image 2 Seems download image will follow scrollbar

[image: Seems download image will follow scrollbar]

#### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/puff0211/o3tfs2vh/

---

## Desired download image

#### image - display all items on download image without scrollbar

[image: highcharts with scrollbar display all items]

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    //min: 0,
    //max: 4,
    scrollbar: {
        // enabled: true
    },
    tickLength: 0
},
```

After I disable scrollbar, the download image is correct, but I need the scrollbar on page...

#### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/puff0211/o3tfs2vh/1/

Does anyone know to accomplish following conditions?

1. highcharts with scrollbar on page
2. display all items on download image without scrollbar

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define options for an exported chart by setting [exporting.chartOptions](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting).

Disable scrollbar and reset min/max values:

```
exporting: {
  chartOptions: {
    xAxis: {
      scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
      },
      min: undefined,
      max: undefined
    }
  }
},
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/rr8pxoLx/

Comment: I am not yet familiar with this document. Thank you for suggesting this setting.

Comment: @morganfree check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yL5hca0x/)  it is more close to OP requirement .

Comment: This solution doesn't worked for me. Chart still exporting with the scrollbar in the jsfiddle. ¿There is any good solution?